# How to get all comments from a Youtube video

Tags: php, json, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Firstly, I looked all of other title. All of them out of date. I mean, they are use old api.

I write a code to list all comments with their `nextPageToken`

---

```
<?php
$url      = "SE0wDh_pILk"; // Youtube video ID
$ytkey    = "IzaSyCaRXmJ9XDC4XucAZCzXx7hisCtYEH0mNs"; //"IzaSyBuu-rnbmPAj1DjR6WmyxGmpmQKz8aTXbw"  Your api key
$nextPage = ""; // Next Page Token for get comments of next Page.
//$i =0; // DO NOT CHANGE


for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $str = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=" . "$ytkey" . "&textFormat=plainText&part=snippet&videoId=" . "$url" . "&maxResults=100&nextPagetoken=" . "$nextPage");

    $json = json_decode($str, true); // decode the JSON into an associative array
    //echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>'; // Print json data as array structer ..

    echo "$i - " . "Next Page Token : " . $json['nextPageToken']; // Take the next Page Token for get next 100 comment...
    echo "<hr>"; // Divider


    $nextPage = $json['nextPageToken']; // Take token for next query
    // print comments.

    foreach ($json['items'] as $val) { // Loop for list comments...
        $author  = $val['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorDisplayName']; //Get Comment Author Name.
        //$author_url = $val['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorChannelUrl']; //Get Comment Author URL.
        //$author_thumbnail_url = $val['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorProfileImageUrl']; //Get Comment Author Thumbnail URL.
        $comment = $val['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']; //Get Comment Content.

        echo "<span style='color:red';>" . "$author" . "</span>" . " --> " . "$comment"; // Author and comment
        echo "<hr>"; // Divider
    }

}

echo "Process over. ";
?>
```

---

I learn how to parse json and how to show them on php from stackoverflow.

Now, there is no problem with taking nextPageTokens. But I can't get comments.

When I run the script, It returns different `nextPageToken` but comments are same, they come from the first page.

I try to add enough comment line.
Sorry I can't color the php codes.

Comment: Any reason why you are doing this manually and not using the Google PHP client library?  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: could you extend your answer?

Comment: Right now you are coding this all yourself.   There is a library created by Google for PHP which will do all of this for you.   You are making it harder on yourself then it needs to be https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#create_and_manage_comments

Comment: that functions cannot satisfy my requests, I want to get all comment this scripts only can look most common comments and reply them..

Comment: is it really a good idea to post your API key publicly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found a site that does what I want to do.

If you have to collect all comments of a video and take one of them randomly for lottery etc. , use these sites ->
https://www.randomcommentpicker.com
http://commentpicker.com/youtube.html

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `commentThreads` with the parameter `&nextPagetoken=`.

The correct parameter to use is `&pageToken=`.

Comment: Same result :(  tokens are ok. but comments are same .

Comment: For the video ID SE0wDh_pILk in your code, the totalResults is 90, less than the 100 requested. Honestly I don't know why YouTube returns a nextPageToken in this case, as there is only 1 page of results.

Comment: in video, page says "there are more than 200 comments. But show only about 100 in json

Comment: If you want comment replies as well, you need to request part=snippet,replies

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive,bare bones function to return all comments from a video

```
public function getAllComments($videoId,$pageToken=null,$maxResults){
        $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads";

        static $all =[];
        $params =[
            'key' => 'your-key',
            'part' => 'snippet',
            'maxResults' => $maxResults,
            'videoId' => $videoId,
            'pageToken' => $pageToken
        ];

        $call = $url.'?'.http_build_query($params);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $call);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $data = NULL;
        $data = json_decode($output,true);
        $all[] = $data;
        if(isset($data['nextPageToken'])){
            if($data['nextPageToken'] != NULL ){
                $pageToken = $data['nextPageToken'];
                getAllComments($videoId,$pageToken,$maxResults);
            }
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $all;


    }
```

Comment: Or use https://youtuberandomcomment.com/ to download comments as json if you dont care about coding.